# simple jQuery not working when uploaded

Tags: jquery

So I've been learning jQuery and fiddling around with basic functions, and testing it in different platforms.

The thing is, the following code works on all the browsers on my mac (Safari, Chrome, Firefox) when it's locally hosted (the file:///Users/Janey/testing/test.html kind of thing), but when it's uploaded, it stops working on everything but Safari (it works on both Safari for Mac and iOS Safari)

Here's the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=0.5 maximum-scale=1.0">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js">  </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/test.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="resources/jquerytest.js"></script>
    <div id="button">button 1</div><br>
    <div id="buttons">button 2</div><br>
    <div id="hide">hider</div><br>
    <div id="show">shower</div><br>
    <div id="toggle">toggler</div><br>
</body>
</html>
```

and the jQuery file is as such:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#show").hide();
    $("#hide").show();
    $("#button").click(function() {
        $("#toggle").toggle();
        $("#hide").hide();
        $("#show").show();
    });
    $("#buttons").click(function() {
        $("#toggle").toggle();
        $("#show").hide();
        $("#hide").show();
    });
});
```

tester is here: https://00c3c1ad2091a7f217bcb0c02dcd4786bc9fd492.googledrive.com/host/0B9xDKEsFy3ddTUZna254Zk1RYlU/test.html

What am I missing? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: it is throwing error. [blocked] The page at 'https://00c3c1ad2091a7f217bcb0c02dcd4786bc9fd492.googledrive.com/host/0B9xDKEsFy3ddTUZna254Zk1RYlU/test.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

try to make reference as https.

Comment: The error is saying that you're mixing HTTP and HTTPS. So reference the api at HTTPS, not HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand further on Akhlesh's comment

If you run your page and press F12 and check the console you'll see the error he is talking about.

Try changing this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

**That's because you are uploading it at the wrong place.**

Online file storage services like Google Drive (as you did) don't support execution of JavaScript (by default, extra steps need to be taken).You may try it locally by opening up a Private Server.

Comment: Javascript is executed in the browser so how does the download source make any difference? The file hosted in Google Drive is simply opened in the browser and that's where the javascript is executed.

Comment: Because google drive doesn't know how we intent to use the file. It's not that it can't be done at all using an online file storage service but then we need to take extra steps to make it work. Example (Hosting steps forGoogle Drive)[http://www.techsperia.blogspot.com/2013/07/how-to-host-javascript-and-css-scripts.html?m=1]

Comment: That link is all about getting the correct URL, nothing about enabling 'supporting execution of javascript'. It looks like the OP has disappeared anyway. I say again - the javascript is executed in the browser and where you download it from makes no difference.

Comment: I think you are getting me wrong!! We are not downloading the file on our Local Drive. **The asker is trying to use Google Drive as a Hosting service.**

The problem here is that this can't be done. When html,css and Javascript files are uploaded on GD, and a public link is created to the .html file (that's linked to a .js file) the JS won't work by default when that page is visited using the public URL. _(at no point the file is explicitly downloaded to the machine)_

Comment: and you are right JavaScript is executed within the browser but viewing it from Google Drive link without modifications in the url (in this case) is _like_ opening a .js file as plain text. you still have the code but it won't work. Maybe not everyone wants that their JS files be executed when viewing on Drive so Google Drive doesn't support it by default. Here's the link from Google Developers [Publish Website Content-Google Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/publish-site)

Comment: Javascript works when uploaded to Google Drive. ElectricLlama was right about the correct URL portion-- my code was trying to use an `http://` link on a secure server and because it lacked that 's' I guess the browser it not secure enough to load (and I guess that kind of thing depends on the browser because it worked fine on Safari, both PC and Mobile) Changing `http://` to `https://` did the job for the other browsers.

Comment: I did a little experiment and you're right - it appears that GDrive explicitly disables the hosting of JS. (utilising nosniff). Obviously because they don't want to be hosting static files for a gazillion websites. I got a bit caught up on your statement 'support the execution of' - it should be 'support the hosting of'. Thanks for teaching me something :)

Comment: Yeah misleading statemnt. My bad.